# How exactly works "put on hold"?

Tags: support

I, the past when I made some migrations to question immediately appear in the appropriate site.

Now everything first goes to a state of "Put on Hold". I don't know who, when or where can make this hold end and make the migration complete.

Those thinks appear to other moderator to them approve or it is something automatic?

Who change the hold status?

Where can this think be changed?

When this is eligible to the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "on hold" thing was introduced a while back so that users didn't feel so discouraged when their topic was closed, so it is a bit of a nicer way to encourage them to edit their question and get it reopened.

You can get most of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

> Questions are marked [on hold] for the first five days after closure
>   to encourage edits and improvements to the question. If a question is
>   edited by the original poster when it is marked [on hold], it will
>   automatically be placed in a review queue to be considered for
>   reopening. If it is not reopened within five days, the [on hold]
>   notice automatically changes to [closed]. There is functionally no
>   difference between an [on hold] question and a [closed] one; neither
>   can be answered until it is re-opened, but they both allow comments,
>   votes and edits.

Comment: I think every time I try to migrate a post with "this belongs to Stack Overflow" path it goes to "on hold". But if instead I select "it belongs to another Q&A" I migrate instantaneously.