# Why does close as Off Topic in case of Sotware Development have two different behavior?

Tags: feature-request, bug, moderators

I asked some time ago [how `[Put on Hold]` works](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/q/201/60) and really understood.

But looks like we have an inconsistence in the behavior when I close to close as ***Off-Topic*** for almost the same reason.

[image: Closing as Off-Topic]

In this case I can close because the question belongs to *Stack Overflow* in two different ways:

1. First option will `[Put on Hold]` the question, write it as a comment about why it was closed and will migrate after some days.
2. Fourth option will instanlty migrate to *Stack Overflow* (after I choose it in next screen).

   I think the behavior of this two options should be the same. Or both `[Put on Hold]` for some time or both migrate instantly.

Answer (score 4):

The fourth option, with the "browse for any site" option is only available to moderators (and employees of Stack Exchange), whilst the first, and the migrate to meta on the fourth are available to the wider community.

To get sites added to the list of sites on the fourth option requires the site to be out of beta, and also requires proof that there is sufficient volume of migrations; Then the moderators can approach the staff at Stack Exchange to get it added as an option; it is not a self-service option at time of writing.

Comment: So we, as ♦, should choose the 4th option by default?

Comment: I'd suggest it's the only time a moderator should cast anything other than the last close vote, when it clearly is a coding question. As an aside, I've seen [other questions](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/8890/106) with this close reason as a vote, where I'd see them as better suited to this site, which is why I think it's important that closure for off-topicness should be driven by the whole community

Comment: I thought the same thing regard this question .